# Unbiased estimation of $\mathbb{P}(X < Y)$

Tags: estimation

Suppose that I observe i.i.d. draws of two independent variables, $X$ and $Y$. My goal is to estimate $\mathbb{P}(X < Y)$, preferably in a consistent and unbiased way. How exactly should I do this?

*Example and proposed approach*. To illustrate, suppose that my draws of $X$ are $(1,2,1,2)$ whereas my draws of $Y$ are $(2,3,2,3)$.

The obvious procedure is to assume that the sample distributions exactly matches the underlying probability distributions. In this example, this would imply that $X = 1$ with probability 1/2 and $X = 2$ with the remaining probability; likewise, $Y$ is equally likely to be 2 or 3. Once we have got this far, it’s very easy to compute $\mathbb{P}(X < Y)$, say by simulation. In this toy example, no simulation is needed since
$$
\mathbb{P}(X<Y)=1−\mathbb{P}(X=2, Y=2)= 0.75
$$

I believe that this method is consistent: is it also unbiased?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the case of discrete distributions you can compute this probability as

$$P(X<Y) = \sum_{\forall y} P(Y=y) \cdot P(X<y)$$

Since we have

- estimates of $P(Y=y)$ and $P(X<y)$ based on observed frequencies will be unbiased.
- products of independent unbiased variables are themselves unbiased
- sums of unbiased values are themselves unbiased.

it follows that the estimate of $P(X<Y)$ is unbiased.

Comment: I am not sure how to convert this proof to continuous distributions, but intuitively I would say that the logic should work as well for continuous distributions.

Comment: Wouldn't you integrate over a delta distribution in the continuous case?

Comment: @Ggjj11 yes something like that. Intuitively that makes sense, but it needs to be formulated rigourously. In the proof above I make use of the fact that the estimate of $P(Y=y)$, by using the observed frequencies, is unbiased. I don't see how the continuous case will break the logic behind that argument, but it does  need to be formulated differently.

Comment: "products of independent unbiased variables are themselves unbiased" But often $\mathbb{E}[XY] \neq \mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$; I guess I'm missing something here?

Comment: @afreelunch the condition that they are independent makes an important difference. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $E[XY] = E[X] E[Y]$.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus OK thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 9):

Another slightly different approach to the same thing is to realise that your estimator is just (a multiple of) the Mann-Whitney $U$-statistic
$$U=\frac{1}{mn}\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n I(X_i< Y_j)$$
The expectation of this is exactly
$$U=E[I(X<Y)]$$
because that's the expectation of every term in the sum.  It doesn't matter that they are not independent; expectations add regardless of correlation.

If $X$ and $Y$ are continuous, the $U$-statistic approach also straightforwardly gives you the variance and a variance estimator and asymptotic Normality.

Answer (score 7):

For the case of continuous and independent random variables, with distribution functions $F_x, F_y$ marginal densities $f_x, f_y$ and joint density $f_{xy}$,

$$\Pr\left(X < Y\right) = \Pr\left(X \leq Y\right)= \int_{y=-\infty}^{y=\infty}\int_{s=-\infty}^{s=y}f_{xy}(s,y)ds dy $$

$${\rm [independence]}= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{y}f_x(s) f_y(y)ds dy $$

$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_y(y)\int_{-\infty}^{y}f_x(s) ds dy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_y(y) F_x(y)dy = E_y[F_x(Y)].$$

This is the same result as in the discrete case, but here instead of discrete probabilities we use the density as the weighting scheme.

To turn this into an empirical estimation formula, to estimate $F_x(Y)$ we use the empirical distribution function of $X$ at every observed value of $Y$, $\{y_1,...,y_j,...,y_m\}$,
$$\widehat F_x(y_j) = \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^nI\{x_i \leq y_j\}.$$

As regards the density $f_y(y)$ of $Y$, we could use kernel density estimation, but I suspect we would lose unbiasedness.  But we can also simply take the non-weighted average of the $\widehat F_x(y_j)$ terms:

$$\widehat \Pr\left(X \leq Y\right) = \sum_{j =1}^m \frac{1}{m}\left(\frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^nI\{x_i \leq y_j\}\right)$$

Treating the $\{y_j\}$ as fixed (so, "for any realized sample from $Y$"), this is unbiased, and certainly asymptotically consistent.

**Note:** We generally expect that $m\approx n$ or even $m=n$ if we have a continuous r.v. that indeed behaves as a continuous r.v. in the sample (which doesn't always happen), and in any case we expect that $m$ (the distinct values of realized $Y$) will grow with $n$.

Comment: Nice representation, $E_y[F_x(y)]$, that solves the problem in my answer.

Comment: If the random variables X and Y are not independent, I can still draw n paired samples $(X_i, Y_i)$ and compute the estimate $\hat{PR}(X\leq Y)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n I(x_i<y_i)$, to estimate $PR(X<Y)= \int_{y=-\infty}^\infty dy  \int_{x=-\infty}^y P(X=x,Y=y)dx. $ This can be rewritten to be $PR(X<Y)=\int_{y=-\infty}^\infty dy  \int_{x=-\infty}^y P(X=x|Y=y) P(Y=y) dx = E_Y[F_{X|Y}(Y)]$, where $F_{X|Y}$ is a conditional cumulative distribution function. Right?

Comment: @Ggjj11 Indeed, this is the case by Bayes theorem for densities.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple approach:
You can pair the observations $(X_i,Y_i)$.
Then, you can create Bernoulli random variables from your data:
$1\{X_i<Y_i\}$, i.e. this random variable is $1$ if $X_i<Y_i$ and 0 else.
Then, you can estimate $\mathbb{P}[X<Y]$ using the empirical mean (which I will denote by $\hat{\theta}_n$):
$$
\hat{\theta}_n:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n1\{X_i<Y_i\}
$$
So, you are just calculating how many times $X_i$ is smaller than $Y_i$ on average in your dataset.
This estimator is unbiased, since:
$$
\mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}_n]=\mathbb{P}[X<Y]
$$
You also have consistency: by the (strong) law of large numbers $\hat{\theta}_n\rightarrow \mathbb{P}[X<Y]$ almost surely.
Moreover, by the central limit theorem you have asymptotic normality:
$$
\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}_n-\mathbb{P}[X<Y])\rightarrow\mathcal{N}(0,\mathbb{P}[X<Y]\mathbb{P}[X\geq Y])
$$

Comment: Using the paired cases will create a less accurate estimate than the situation that is in the question. It is also not answering the question about the bias of the method described in the question.

Comment: It is an answer to: "My goal is to estimate P(X<Y), preferably in a consistent and unbiased way. How exactly should I do this?"

Comment: Thanks for this. I know it's strictly off topic (given the way I put the question), but I suppose that pairing the observations in this way is less efficient than the method I propose?

Comment: Yes, also think that pairing will be less efficient in most situations. To what extent/in what sense will depend on the data generating process.